# Prove this integral is zero

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R} dz \exp\left(iaz^2\right) = 0$, where $a$ has a positive imaginary part and $C_R$ is an arc from $R$ to $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}R$ along the circle centered around the origin with radius $R$.

This is what I have so far:
[image: my attempt]

But this proof does not go through unfortunately.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753676/proving-that-the-line-integral-int-gamma-2-eix2-mathrmdx-tends-t/753700#753700

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the complex function
$$
f(z)=e^{i\alpha z^2}, \ z=re^{i\theta}, \ f(z=re^{i\theta})=e^{i\alpha r^2 e^{2 i\theta}}.
$$
Thus we can analyze the term
$$
f(z=re^{i\theta})=e^{i\alpha r^2 e^{2 i\theta}}
$$
and notice for $\theta=\pi/4$, this is just a real Gaussian integral $\alpha >0$.  If $\theta=0$ we have $f(re^{i\theta})=e^{i\alpha r^2}$.  Thus we split our contour into three pieces making an angle between the imaginary and real axis of $45^o$.  The contour is shown here http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Fresnel_Integral_Contour.svg .  We know there are no poles inside the contour and $f(z)$ is holomorphic , thus by the Cauchy Goursat theorem we know we know
\begin{equation}
0=\oint f(z) dz=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{i\alpha x^2} dx +\int_{0}^{\pi/4} ire^{i\theta}  d\theta e^{i\alpha r^2(\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta))}+\int_{\infty}^{0}e^{-\alpha r^2}e^{i\pi/4}dr 
\end{equation}
where the integral is broken up into three contours shown in the illustration and I used $z=re^{i\theta}, \ dz= e^{i\theta }dr$.  The difficult integral to evaluate is 
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/4} ire^{i\theta}  d\theta e^{i\alpha r^2(\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta))},
$$
however it vanishes as $r \to \infty$.  We need to show that it vanishes, it is similar to Jordan's inequality, but that just places an upper bound on the integral,
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-r\sin\theta}d\theta \ < \frac{\pi}{r} \ (r >0).
$$
We will prove this now by showing that 
$$
\lim_{r\to \infty} \bigg| \int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^{i\alpha r^2 e^{2i\theta}} ir e^{i\theta }d\theta \bigg|=0.
$$
We know that 
$$
\bigg| \int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^{i\alpha r^2 e^{2i\theta}} ir e^{i\theta }d\theta \bigg| \leq \int_{0}^{\pi/4} \big|e^{i\alpha r^2 e^{2i\theta}}\big| \big|ir e^{i\theta}d\theta\big|=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} rd\theta \big| e^{i\alpha r^2\cos(2\theta)-\alpha r^2\sin(2\theta)} \big|=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}rd\theta \big|e^{i \alpha r^2\cos(2\theta)}\big|\big|e^{-\alpha r^2 \sin(2\theta)}\big|
$$
where I used $e^{2i\theta}=\cos 2\theta +i\sin 2\theta$.  We can simplify this to obtain
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/4} r d\theta \big|e^{i \alpha r^2\cos(2\theta)}\big|\big|e^{-\alpha r^2\sin(2\theta)}\big|=\int_{0}^{\pi/4} rd\theta e^{-\alpha r^2\sin(2\theta)}.
$$
Thus we need to show that this vanishes as $r \to \infty.$  If we make the substitution $\xi=2\theta , d\theta=d\xi/2$ and changing the bounds of integration we obtain
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{r}{2}d\xi e^{-\alpha r^2\sin \xi}.
$$ 
We can see that for $\xi \in [0,\pi/2]$, $\sin\xi \geq 2\xi/\pi$.  Since $e^{-\alpha r^2\cdot 2\xi/\pi} \geq e^{-\alpha r^2 \sin \xi} $ (since exponential is bigger for a smaller exponent), we can write
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{r}{2}d\xi e^{-\alpha r^2\sin \xi} \leq \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{r}{2}d\xi e^{-\alpha r^2 \cdot 2/\pi}=\frac{\pi}{4 \alpha r}(1-e^{-\alpha r^2}).
$$
Thus it is clear that 
$$
\lim_{r\to \infty}\frac{\pi}{4 \alpha r}(1-e^{-\alpha r^2})=0,
$$
thus we have shown that 
$$
\lim_{r\to \infty} \bigg| \int_{0}^{\pi/4} e^{i\alpha r^2 e^{2i\theta}} ir e^{i\theta }d\theta \bigg|=0.
$$